# Using Locks and Condition to simulate print server

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, java-threads

I want to have print server that outputs the requested messages to the computer screen as follows: Client threads invoke the printRequestV1 method to submit the messages (strings) to be output. But all the printRequestV1 method should do is place the message in the print job queue, and a separate (manager) thread then dequeues messages from the job queue and outputs them to the screen

I know that I need to synchronize the shared request queue and check whether the queue is not empty before trying to remove a message. If the queue is empty, the manager thread needs to wait until client threads add some messages, and the client thread, after adding a message, will let the manager thread know by signaling.

Here what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class PrintServerV1 implements Runnable {

    private static final Queue<String> requests = new LinkedList<String>();
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    public PrintServerV1() {
        try{

          while(requests.size() != 0){ condition.await();}
          new Thread(this).start(); 
        } 
          catch (InterruptedException exception) {}
  }

    public void printRequest(String s) {
        lock.lock();
        try 
        { 
          out.println("Adding print request for: " +s);
          requests.add(s); 
          condition.signalAll();
        } 

        finally { lock.unlock(); }

    }

    public void sendRequest() throws InterruptedException 
    {
      try {

        while(requests.size() != 0){ condition.await();}
        out.println("Sending Request to printer");
        for(;;) realPrint(requests.remove());

      } finally { lock.unlock(); }

    }

   private void realPrint(String s) {
      // do the real work of outputting the string to the screen
      out.println("Currently printing: " + s);
     }

   public void run(){
    try{
      sendRequest();
    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {}
  }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        PrintServerV1 server = new PrintServerV1();
    server.printRequest("homework7.txt");
    }
}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
    Adding print request for: homework7.txt
Sending Request to printer
Currently printing: homework7.txt
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:151)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1261)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:457)
    at PrintServerV1.sendRequest(PrintServerV1.java:43)
    at PrintServerV1.run(PrintServerV1.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My question is wouldn't it better if make two classes, one named manager who implements runnable and whose sole purpose is to remove from the queue and one class named client who implements runnable and whose purpose is to add requests to the queue?

Comment: Your question is a bit of a non-sequitur from the exception message. Are you trying to fix the error you have in your code (on topic), or get an opinion on  your design (off topic)?

Answer (score 0):

- You can only `unlock` after you aquire the lock by `lock`, otherwise `IllegalMonitorStateException` will be thrown. You should also call `await` method after you aquiring the lock.
- It is a bad idea to `await` in the construtor, it will cause the creation of instance get blocked;
- Remove the elements only when the `requests` is not empty.

This code works fine on my machine:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class PrintServerV1 implements Runnable {

    private static final Queue<String> requests = new LinkedList<String>();
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    public void printRequest(String s) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            out.println("Adding print request for: " + s);
            requests.add(s);
            condition.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void sendRequest() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (requests.size() == 0) {
                condition.await();
            }
            out.println("Sending Request to printer");
            while (!requests.isEmpty()) {
                realPrint(requests.remove());
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void realPrint(String s) {
        // do the real work of outputting the string to the screen
        out.println("Currently printing: " + s);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            sendRequest();
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintServerV1 server = new PrintServerV1();
        new Thread(server).start();
        server.printRequest("homework7.txt");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Adding print request for: homework7.txt
Sending Request to printer
Currently printing: homework7.txt
```

---

I suggest to use two threads, one producer and one consumer, as well as a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to solve this kind of problem. The synchronization will be handled by the blocking queue, so you can focus on you business logic.

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedBlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        new Thread(new Producer(queue)).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer(queue)).start();
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> queue;

    public Consumer(LinkedBlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            String request;
            try {
                request = queue.take();
                System.out.println(request);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> queue;

    public Producer(LinkedBlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            queue.put("homework7.txt");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just did but now it only outputs this:
Adding print request for: homework7.txt and the program never ends